# Getting bean error even after deleting the Daos/controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

I keep getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: testDao controller.testController.testDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [testDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Even when I delete this testController and DAO I still keep getting it even though my other controllers etc. are working perfectly fine. I tried clearing the cache/index file but that didn't seem to solve it for me. Is it still cached somewhere? Or are there any solutions to my problem?

Comment: Are you propertly building and deploying the updated WAR?

Comment: Check you xml config if you have one to remove the controllers and DAOs. If you have cleared them, then it is build problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `.class` files for your Controller and Dao are probably still in the build directory. Try cleaning  and rebuilding  your project  by clicking  `Run > Clean and Build Project..` in Netbeans.
Edit: If you run it on a server, try deleting the project from a server and deploying it again.

Comment: Tried that a lot of times, no succes.

Comment: Did you check the build directory for your project? Can you see testController there? If no, what is your configuration?